# Maximum Likelihood Estimation three-parameter Weibull for right censored data

Tags: r, weibull, mle

I am trying to estimate the parameters of the three-parametric Weibull distribution with ML for censored data.

I've worked it out by using the package `flexsurv` where I've defined an "own" density function.

I've also followed the instructions given in the documentation of the function `flexsurv::flexsurvreg`to build the list with all required information to do the MLE with a customer density function.

In the following you can see what I've done so far.

```
library(FAdist)
library(flexsurv)

set.seed(1)
thres <- 3500
data <- rweibull(n = 1000, shape = 2.2, scale = 25000) + thres
y <- sample(c(0, 1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(x = data, status = y)

dweib3 <- function(x, shape, scale, thres, log = FALSE) {
    dweibull(x - thres, shape, scale, log = log)
}

pweib3 <- function(q, shape, scale, thres, log_p = FALSE) {
    pweibull(q - thres, shape, scale, log.p = log_p)
}

# Not required
#qweib3 <- function(p, shape, scale, thres, log.p = FALSE) {
#   if (log.p == TRUE) {
#        p <- exp(p)
#    }
#    qwei3 <- thres + qweibull(p, shape, scale)
#    return(qwei3)
#}
dweib3 <- Vectorize(dweib3)
pweib3 <- Vectorize(pweib3)

custom.weibull <- list(name = "weib3", 
    pars = c('shape', 'scale', 'thres'), location = 'scale', 
    transforms = c(log, log, log), 
    inv.transforms = c(exp, exp, exp), 
    inits = function(t) { 
        c(1.2 / sqrt((var(log(t)))), exp(mean(log(t)) + (.572 / (1.2 / sqrt((var(log(t))))))), .5 * min(t))
        }
        )
ml <- flexsurvreg(Surv(df1$x, df1$status) ~ 1, data = df1, dist = custom.weibull)
```

The variable y should represent the status of a unit where 1 is a failure and 0 is an unfailed unit until censoring.

The initial values for shape and scale are taken from the moments which are also defined in the `fitdistrplus`package.

For the threshold parameter there must be a constraining since the threshold must be really smaller than the minimum of the data. Therefore a constraint of threshold is at its max .99 * t_min would be satisfactory (this is something which I haven't implement until now).

The output of the above MLE is the following:

```
> ml
Call:
flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(df1$x, df1$status) ~ 1, data = df1, 
    dist = custom.weibull)

Estimates: 
       est       L95%      U95%      se      
shape  2.37e+00  2.12e+00  2.65e+00  1.33e-01
scale  3.52e+04  3.32e+04  3.74e+04  1.08e+03
thres  2.75e+03  1.51e+03  5.02e+03  8.44e+02

N = 1000,  Events: 481,  Censored: 519
Total time at risk: 25558684
Log-likelihood = -5462.027, df = 3
AIC = 10930.05
```

The estimated parameters aren't fine even if there is censoring.
I've did this procedure a few times with other randomly generated data... the estimates are always pretty far away from the "truth".

Therefore I need an improvement of my code or another possibility to estimate the parameters of a three-parameter Weibull with MLE.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your aim is: 1. what are the parameters that you have to estimate? 2. Are there any fixed parameters, known on forehand  (e.g. the threshold)? 3. Please define "..aren't fine": by what criterion would you conclude that the estimated parameters are "fine", that is what values of shape, scale, thres would you accept as correctly estimated/satisfactorily close to the "truth"?

Comment: My aim is to code a function where I can easily get out the estimated parameters of a three-parameter Weibull distribution in case of right censored data. This is just preparation for the function by testing the functionality. I want to estimate the shape, scale and threshold parameter of the weibull distribution. The threshold parameter is truly constrained in the case of where the shape parameter is smaller than 1. Hence I have to do constrained MLE in this case (not implemented because shape is bigger 1 in this example).

Comment: I've learned that the standard error tells something about the reliability of the applied estimation method. I would say that the standard errors for scale and threshold are really big. in case that the data generating distribution was the three-parametric weibull.. also the log likelihood value is pretty small but I'm not pretty sure whether the log likelihood could be bigger than zero in this case. However, if 0 would be the optimum I would say that - 5500 is pretty far away.. without a knowledgable explanation.